# Multiple sessions for one user?

Tags: java, jsp, session, jakarta-ee, servlets

Hi I have host web application which is developed using java and jsp. In client side each client give five ajax calls to the server to retrieve data from the server in every 30 seconds.
My problem is can one user who use one browser to log in to the system have multiple session at a time. Reason is when i use the tool to use monitor the firewall I can see more than 10 sessions are active for one IP. How this can happen? any comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Another browser application can be used.
- Some browsers doesn't take session from already running browser instance
- 2 or more user behind the same proxy, will end-up having the same IP (provider's IP)

Comment: Actually adeel problem is not only with one user but actualy with each user. Firewall monitoring tool shows more  than 5 sessions with each user. Can this happen. Is there are a problem with ajax requests

Comment: @ganuke: Try your firewall monitoring tool for some other websites.

Answer (score 1):

1.The IP you see is Public IP which could be same for multiple users hence you see multiple 
calls from same IP.

1. A single user using different browsers will have same IP but will show up as 10 calls in your log.